Should I use a separate algolia index for each product category?
I'm setting up a web store, storing the products in Algolia, and interacting with it via PHP and JS. I'm struggling to understand what the best configuration would be.
I have a wide variety of products, with different properties. Should I set up one index for each product category, to facilitate faceting? Or would I be better off using a single index and configure each entry? Is there a best practice?
Thanks.

I would say use one index, until you notice that you need more control.
However, if you're planning on multi-language search, multiple indexes is the way to go. https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/optimize-search-results/handling-natural-languages-nlp/
